# Local Variable Declaration Issue

Tags: c#

Im getting the following error:

> Cannot use local variable 'dob' before it is declared

Here is my implementation

```
public class Person
    {
        ...
        public string dob { get; set; }
        ...

       public int getAge()
       {
                DateTime origin = DateTime.Parse(dob);
                return DateTime.Today.Year - origin.Year;
        }

        public string getFormattedDoB()
        {
                DateTime origin = DateTime.Parse(dob);
                string dob = origin.ToString("d");
                return dob;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what to make of this because it is complaining about it's use of dob in `getFormattedDoB()` but not in `getAge()` which comes before it. If anyone could shed some light on this that would be great

Comment: Can you explain why `dob` is not `DateTime`? You would need a pretty good reason to use `string` over a specific type.

Comment: It's part of a merger program that retrieves information from a Unix based program, so it's easier to transport the time in seconds as a string and parse into the DateTime on the Windows end

Comment: OK but it seems rather pointless to parse the string every time. Why not simply do it once?

Comment: This is the first iteration of the program, that was one of many future  optimization i have planned

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've declared a local variable in getFormattedDoB called dob. The compiler can't tell the difference between that and the member dob. Try adding "this" where you mean the member variable rather than the local:

```
DateTime origin = DateTime.Parse(this.dob);
```

Better still, don't use the same name for the local variable.

Edit: Unless you did actually intended to set the member variable and not create a new one. In which case remove the "string" as Andrew suggested.

Comment: Thanks for that i didn't pick that up ><

Comment: The error is *not* that the compiler cannot tell the difference; the compiler *can* tell the difference. Rather, the error is **the error that is actually reported**. A local variable is in scope throughout the block; it is an error to use it *before the declaration*.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have two `dob`s- the property and the local variable.  The scope of a variable declaration (`string dob = ...`) is the whole block (everything between the `{` and `}`).  Therefore the compiler thinks that on the line:

```
DateTime origin = DateTime.Parse(dob);
```

you are using the `dob` *variable* before it is declared, when (we assume) you really meant the `dob` *property*.

As others have mentioned, you should rename the property.  The standard naming convention in C# would be

```
public String DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
//(assuming that is what DOB stands for)
```

or better yet

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reused the variable name "dob" in `getFormattedDoB` as a local string, which is confusing the compiler.  There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Rename the local dob in getFormattedDoB (which you really should do because it's good practice).
2. Use this.dob in the following line to specify the class level variable (which you should probably also do because it's also good practice:

   DateTime origin = DateTime.Parse(this.dob);

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring dob  in

```
string dob = origin.ToString("d");
```

it should be

```
 dob = origin.ToString("d");
```