# Not an error to use a variable before it is declared?

Tags: java, locals

What are the rules for initialization of local variables before the point they are declared? Is it possible to use a variable before it is declared? I see on this page ([Local Variable Declaration Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116355/local-variable-declaration-issue)) that it is illegal, yet when I try it works:

```
public static String toHelp = "--help";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toHelp);
    String toHelp = args[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're confused is that the rules of local variable scoping are different in C# and Java - For Java (you posted the question with a Java tag) the scope begins at the point where the variable declaration occurs and extends downward to the end of the enclosing block. So in your example the `println` actually doesn't take the local variable into account but the static field because the local variable was technically not in scope at that point.

If you did the same thing in C# (the link you included is for C# and not Java) you would indeed get an error. There the rules of scoping are different - in C# the the scope of a variable is the entire enclosing block, so it also includes the statements that precede the declaration but appear in the block. If your sample was C#, the first statement in `main` would be accessing a non-initialized variable and that is a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toHelp); // using the already initialize static variable
    String toHelp = args[0]; // shadowing the static variable with a local variable
}
```

Shadowing is explained in the [Java Language Specification here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

After the execution of

```
String toHelp = args[0];
```

you have two variables with the name `toHelp` in scope. The local one can be accessed with its name `toHelp`. The class `static` variable needs to now be accessed with `ClassName.toHelp` because it is shadowed.

Comment: I don't think it comes under shadowing, A brand new method's local variable created, right ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ JLS states _Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity._ I think that applies here. There's even an example in the link I posted.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm thinking that shadow concept applies to type, sub type relation only :), I guess I have to go through that link carefully once.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String toHelp = "--help";
```

You already declared it and defined it equal to "--help".

The scanner input would just set it again.

Answer (score 0):

`toHelp` is a static variable. Its visible to your `main()` as its already declared and initialized.

And if you're asking about the `args`, then its a method parameter and therefore, its already declared as a part of the method declaration itself.

If its a instance variable, then you can use `this.toHelp` to access that in the method. And (as in this case) its a static variable and you can use the ClassName.toHelp to differentiate the 2 variables.

Comment: For Java: Would the second declaration of 'toHelp' create a new local variable (within function-level scope), masking the file-scope variable?  If so how would you differentiate between the two later in the function?  (Answered above by Sotirios Delimanolis: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19335195/1364365 )

Comment: If its a instance variable, then you use `this.toHelp`. But in this case, its a static variable and so you can use the `ClassName.toHelp` to differentiate them.