# Cannot use local variable "location "berfor it is declared.The declaration of local variable hides the field "sloution.Form.location"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code

```
public static string mSearchBy = "";
        TextBox LocationName;
        TextBox LocationID;
        TextBox ManufactureName;
        TextBox ManufactureID;
        TextBox UOMName; TextBox UOMID; 
        TextBox CategoryName; TextBox CategoryID;
        TextBox DepartmentName; TextBox DepartmentID;



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //DB = new LQMasterAssetDataContext();
            mobjGenlib = new clsGeneralLib();
            //For User Control Definition
            ManufactureName = (TextBox)(Manufacturer.FindControl("Account"));
            ManufactureID = (TextBox)(Manufacturer.FindControl("AccountID"));
            //UOMName = (TextBox)(UOM.FindControl("UOMType"));
            //UOMID = (TextBox)(UOM.FindControl("UOMTypeID"));
            CategoryID = (TextBox)(AssetCategory.FindControl("AssetCategoryID"));
            CategoryName = (TextBox)(AssetCategory.FindControl("AssetCategory"));
            **LocationName = (TextBox)(Location.FindControl("Location"));"
            LocationID = (TextBox)(Location.FindControl("LocationID"));"**

................and so on
        }
```

Getting the above mentioned error near `Location.FindControl()`.....can any one help me to resolve this...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is `Location` in your form? is it a panel?

Comment: Location is an UserControl......

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the question's current state, I doubt any answer would be anything more than speculation as `Location` isn't defined in the given code.

Comment: Actually, try looking at this (gotten from Googling your error excluding your specific variable names) - [Local Variable Declaration Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10116355). If that doesn't help you figure it out, you should post a complete example.

Comment: Have i found the solution for my Above issue;


In my project in the .aspx page i changed the name to AssetLocation instead of location...it works fine.

Note- "
Within a method of a class that has a local variable named similar to its field, the local variable hides the field while accessing it within the method. It is more efficient to use a local variable than a field."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Location` is the field/property of `Form`, you need to change the name of user control to something else.

Comment: Correct. Alternatively he could use `this.Location` instead of just `Location` to make sure he refers to the (inherited) class member (property) and not the local variable `Location` that is declared inside the same scope `{ ... }` in the same method. The error was confusing because just `Location` worked for him initially; only after he introduced the local variable by that name later in the method body text, the problem arose. **Tip** for him: Use lower-casing like `location` for local variables, then conflicts like this become rare.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are trying to Find a control with the Name `Location` from the UserControl named `Location`.

**Solution :** I suspect that you want to find a control named `LocationName` on UserControl `Location`

Try This:

```
    TextBox AssetLocationName;
    TextBox AssetLocationID;

    AssetLocationName = (TextBox)(Location.FindControl("LocationName"));"
    AssetLocationID = (TextBox)(Location.FindControl("LocationID"));"
```

Comment: Tried that also Getting same error.......

Comment: "(TextBox)(Location.FindControl" in both lines it was underlining the word location with red line saying as cannot use local variable "Location"before it is declared.

Comment: try this -> `(TextBox)(Location.FindControl("LocationName"));`

Comment: I'm using like that only This was my code LocationID = (TextBox)(Location.FindControl("LocationID"));

Comment: you can not find `Location` from `Location` so tell me from the `Location` which one you want to find?

Comment: Except location remaining user controls "Manufacturer,Category" all working fine :(

Comment: did you try this -> try this -> `(TextBox)(Location.FindControl("LocationName"));`

Comment: Actually Location is an Usercontrol and i'm getting the location name and location id from that...

Comment: Ya tried that it keep on showing the same error in the word "location".findcontrol.

Comment: Have i found the solution for my Above issue;


In my project in the .aspx page i changed the name to AssetLocation instead of location...it works fine.

Note- "
Within a method of a class that has a local variable named similar to its field, the local variable hides the field while accessing it within the method. It is more efficient to use a local variable than a field."